# How do I get play store to stop asking me to auto-update on wifi?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I have an Acer Iconia A200 running Android 4.0.3. Lately whenever I update an app, the Play Store asks me (via a pop-up dialog) if I want to automatically update apps on Wi-Fi. The only answers I can give are 'yes' and 'not now'.

What I really want is 'No, and don't ask again', because I happen to like being involved in updates.

In Play Store->settings->auto update, automatic update is turned off, and has no setting for 'Wi-Fi only'.

Is there any way to turn this annoying message off? I'm very afraid I'm going accidentally answer yes one day and thus lose control of my updates.

Updated: Play store says build 4.0.27 in it's 'Build Version' in the play store settings.

Updated again: It's back. The exact message is 'Update Apps automatically when on Wi-Fi?' and the two options to the dialog are 'Not now' and 'OK'. Interestingly this happened when I updated 'GOdroid' directly from the page, but did NOT happen when I updated 5 other apps at once later that day. I'm wondering if it's only asking once per app or something?

Comment: What version of the play store do you have? I'm on 3.10.14 and do not seem to have this issue of a "popup". In Settings there is the option "Update over Wi-Fi only" but this is unchecked and toggling this option does not produce a popup for me.

Comment: @w3d - added to the question.

Comment: Could you please check the popup message carefully and let us know whether it really asks about actually *updating apps* or rather *check for updates* when on wifi? There is an option to restrict the check etc. to Wifi only, so it would at least correspond. Maybe you simply misinterpreted the message, which might happen easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since been updated to 4.0.27 and although I got prompted after my first app update as to whether I want to auto-update next time (no mention of Wi-Fi though, although I suspect this is dependent on your settings) to which I responded "Not Now", I have not been prompted since in subsequent updates for other apps.

> In Play Store->settings->auto update, automatic update is turned off, and has no setting for 'wi-fi only'.

In version 4.0.27 there should still be a 'Wi-Fi only' setting, although it is now (hidden) under the "Auto-update apps" sub menu. In Settings, *tap* the "Auto-update apps" option:

[image: Play Store Settings]

[image: Play Store Settings - Auto update apps]

**Update 2013-05-11:** I've had quite a few updates for various apps over the past week and not been re-prompted to *auto-update next time* - that is, until today. Today I got prompted, to which I tapped "Not Now" again. I have not been re-prompted since. Perhaps it prompts once a week or every so many updates?

[image]

Comment: I had some updates last night and no recurrance of the issue. The A200 is wi-fi only (which is, I assume, why I don't have a wi-fi only setting), and I'm suspecting that the auto update state got screwed up somehow. Then, when I went into the menus looking for how to turn it off before posting, I ended up forcing it into the true 'do not auto-update' state.